# How to implement the google sign-in in a UIButton rather than a UIView using google sign-in sdk?

Tags: swift, google-signin

Friends i am a ios swift learner at the post beginner level. I have been trying to do a google sign-in in my try-up app. Based on the resources from google developers and other tutorials i am successfully able to do the sign in using the **UIView** . Then i was trying to implement the same code in the action block of a UIButton which does not work for me. I want to place a custom image in the UIButton with no text. I tried many search engines which does not provide a clear answer. Please someone guide me

```
@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = self.myClientId
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
```

`
Here signInButton outlet is a UIView.
Please Tell me how to implement it into a UIButton's Touch-up inside action block or just a way to change the default icon that the google sdk returns.

Note: I am using Google-Sign-In SDK not Google-Plus-Sign-In SDK as it is Deprecated by google. Also no errors in the bridging headers , other Linker flags , URL Schema and GoogleSignIn Framework integration.

Please someone guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For G login and custom buton login you can check sample  https://github.com/kamleshk/Google-Sign-Up

Answer (score 15):

Create your button on storyboard or programatically and on button action just do this.

```
@IBAction func googleSignInClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

Implement the delegate function:

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

}
```

to get the response.

Answer (score 4):

Here i use code like:

In **AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Initialize sign-in
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.

        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
}
 func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
}
```

In **LoginViewController.swift**

```
 @IBAction func btnGoogleLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
func signInWillDispatch(signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: NSError!) {
    //myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}

// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
    presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //print("Sign in presented")
}
  // Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
    dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
       // print("Sign in dismissed")
}
 func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!){
    let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
    let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
    let fullName = user.profile.name
    let givenName = user.profile.givenName
    let familyName = user.profile.familyName
    let email = user.profile.email
    print("Welcome: ,\(userId), \(idToken), \(fullName), \(givenName), \(familyName), \(email)")

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let chooseCVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChooseCategeoriesVC") as! ChooseCategeoriesVC
    //chooseCVC.facebookUserDetailsDict = self.facebookUserDict
    chooseCVC.loginTypeString = "Google"
   // let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
   // rootViewController.pushViewController(chooseCVC, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chooseCVC, animated: true)

}

// Finished disconnecting |user| from the app successfully if |error| is |nil|.
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!){

}
```

Comment: Explained!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Add `GIDSignInDelegate` in your UIViewController, and in ViewDidLoad(): `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self`

on button action, do this:

```
@IBAction func btnGoogleLoginOnClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

And implement this delegate function:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let authentication = user.authentication
    print("Access token:", authentication?.accessToken!)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add UIButton to storyboard with your image.

```
@IBAction func googleSignIn(sender: UIButton) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

Delegate implementation will be like this -

```
// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
    presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        print("Sign in presented")

}

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
    dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        print("Sign in dismissed")
}
```

Don't forget to declare delegate 'GIDSignInUIDelegate' in your UIViewController implementation

Answer (score 1):

In swift 4 and 5 simply do that
1-Appdelegate add these two lines but before configure download the infoplist it will generate when you will create OAuth Id below mentioned  GSignID then write these two lines otherwise your app will crash after two or three try

```
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = GSignID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

2-Go to your viewcontroller in which you want to implement google sign in import GIDSignInDelegate

```
extension RegisterMenuVC : GIDSignInDelegate{
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

        if let error = error {
          if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
            print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
          } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
          }
          return
        }
        print("User details")
        print(user.profile.name)
        print(user.profile.familyName)
        print(user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 200))

        let creds = user.authentication.idToken

    }
}
```

3- Simply call the action in button

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
```